# Is it possible to connect to MySQL from PHP using the old password encryption protocol?

Tags: mysql, php

I am working on a front-end project with a legacy system. I have to access a MySQL 5.6.25 database, which is still using the old pre-4.1 password encryption protocol. In particular I have to write a PHP/Slim api that implements CRUD operations with this database. I have to use PHP 5.3.

Is it possible to connect to the MySQL DB from PHP using the old password encryption protocol? So far I tried the php extensions mysql and mysqli, but they both use the post 4.1 password encription.

I know that the pre-4.1 password encryption protocol is very old, not secure, and should be upgraded. But this is not something I have control on in this project, so I have to find a way to work with this constraint.

Comment: Sorry, you can't do this. The fix for this is to get rid of old passwords.

Comment: @Michael Hampton It looks like the PEAR package DB still supports MySQL <= 4.0, with mysql, and  MySQL >= 4.1 with mysqli (http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.db.intro-dsn.php)

Comment: And, by the way, the PEAR site has a warning that the DB package of PEAR has been superseded, and one should use MDB2 for new projects, http://pear.php.net/package/DB

Comment: In your case I would turn off the password authentication, if there aren't security problems with it.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the option to rebuild PHP without mysqlnd?

If your current build is using it then it'll flat out refuse to have anything to do with the old authentication method and you'll be getting an error along the lines of "mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using the old insecure authentication" in your logs. A build without it might just get you thru, if its an option for you.

Comment: thanks, this provides me with more understanding of how mysql connection works in php. It looks like php 5.3 compile default should be with 'libmysqlclient' instead of the more recent 'mysqlnd' library (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.library.choosing.php). But the mac ios distribution, I installed with 'brew install php53', comes with 'mysqlnd'.